# Python - Receiving more arguments than passing?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning python and gtk and so trying to using cairo to draw a rectangle in the screen with the mouse (I just managed to draw a rectangle without mouse).

However something strange is happening since I'm receiving more arguments than what I'm passing. How is that possible?

draw_rectangle - method definition:

```
def draw_rectangle (self, widget, start_x_cood, start_y_cood, ending_x_cood, ending_y_cood):
    print ("draw_retangle")
    cr = cairo.Context ()
    cr.set_source_rgba(1, 1, 1, 1)
    cr.rectangle(start_x_cood, start_y_cood, ending_x_cood, ending_y_cood)
    cr.fill()
```

Method that calls draw_rectangle:

```
def on_motion_notify_event (self, widget, event):
        print("on_motion_notify_event")
        if event.is_hint:
            x, y, state = event.window.get_pointer()
        else:
            x = event.x
            y = event.y
            state = event.state

        if self.firstClick :
            self.ending_x_cood = x
            self.ending_y_cood = y
            self.draw_rectangle(self, widget, self.start_x_cood, self.start_y_cood, self.ending_x_cood, self.ending_y_cood)

        return True
```

This is giving me the following error:

> on_motion_notify_event 
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "gui2.py", line 56, in on_motion_notify_event
>       self.draw_rectangle(self, widget, self.start_x_cood, self.start_y_cood, self.ending_x_cood, self.ending_y_cood)
>   TypeError: draw_rectangle() takes exactly 6 arguments (7 given)
>   on_motion_notify_event
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "gui2.py", line 56, in on_motion_notify_event
>       self.draw_rectangle(self, widget, self.start_x_cood, self.start_y_cood, self.ending_x_cood, self.ending_y_cood)
>   TypeError: draw_rectangle() takes exactly 6 arguments (7 given)

Where is that 7th argument coming from?
My searches are leading me to *args and **kwargs but it's not making much sense.

I've uploaded a runnable version of the code [here](https://gist.github.com/fawix/4e55cfb2dc6d302f2093)

Comment: Also, there's no need to pass `self.x`, `self.y` etc from a method to another method inside the same class.

Comment: very true, good point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python passes `self` to instance methods for you, so:

```
self.draw_rectangle(self, widget, self.start_x_cood, self.start_y_cood, self.ending_x_cood, self.ending_y_cood)
```

actually is passing `self` twice.  You want:

```
self.draw_rectangle(widget, self.start_x_cood, self.start_y_cood, self.ending_x_cood, self.ending_y_cood)
```

Comment: Oh! that fixed it! I just removed the self from the call and it worked!